# add fields from different lines in one line

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying to add the .data and .bss sections of the `size -A` output

`size -A mylib.so | grep "\.data" | awk '{print $2}`

this will print the value of the size of the .data section.

I guess I could copy / paste this command inside awk, but this will get ugly fast.

Is there a way to parse several lines like this at once?

Comment: `size -A mylib.so |  awk '/\.data/{printf ("%s ",$2)}END{print ""}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
size -A mylib.so | 
awk '$1 == ".data" || $1 == ".bss" {sum += $2} END {print sum}'
```

If you just want to extract the .data and .bss sizes from the size output, and if you have GNU grep:

```
size -A mylib.so | grep -oP '^(\.data|\.bss)\s+\K\d+'
```

Comment: so awk does parse each line separately by default?

Comment: yes, awk is a "record" oriented tool. By default, the record separator is a newline, meaning each line is a record.